# What, if anything, happens to questions with a negative score?

Tags: support, downvotes

Do questions with a negative score get cleaned up by "the system"? Or do they need to have close votes on them for the questions to be removed?

Comment: They don't appear on the main page (automatic), and are *typically* closed/deleted pretty quickly (manual).

Comment: They get taken out back quietly and shot. Then the bodies are buried where no one will find them.

Comment: @Cupcake I wish I could upvote that comment again. Truly.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

#### Current questions

- At -4, the question does not show up on the front page.

#### All questions

- -1 or lower score, more than 30 days old, no answers, not locked... deleted by Community♦
- 0 score, more than 365 days old, no answers, not locked, low view count, 1 or 0 comments... deleted by Community♦

#### Closed questions

- At -3, enables a speedy delete for 20k users (rather than waiting 2 days)
- Closed more than 9 days ago, not as a duplicate, score less than 0, not locked, no positive score answers, no accepted answer... deleted by Community♦

Further reading:

- [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/213963)
- [Turbocharging the Roomba: solutions for premature deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173513/213963)

Comment: Thank you. So questions with answers stay unless they hit the close queue?

Comment: Correct. Though note questions can be removed from an open question (20k deletes, low quality review, mods, self deletes) which would then cause it to fall into those conditions.

Comment: @ckuhn203 answers do not protect a question from getting closed and deleted. Off topic questions might get answers before being spotted and closed, and then deleted by moderator.