# Why answering in comments is trending?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments

I have been a Stack Overflow user for a while now, and recently I noticed a trend. People tend to reply to questions by using comments, instead of answers. This can be a bit uncomfortable, because

1. comments have to be expanded in order to be visualized as a whole,
2. on the (Android, I don't know about iOS) mobile app, comments are "second-class citizens" (proper answers are dedicated way more space on the screen).

I have the feeling that this is caused by some kind of reverse psychology on gaining reputation. Reputation farming is bad, so people is answering in comments to show that they don't need it. I might be wrong, but if this is the case, I think that we should grow up and use the tools as intended.

Comment: Many people will also post a comment when they're unsure if it will solve their problem or if they're not entirely sure what the problem is in the first place.

Comment: I will frequently point the asker in the right direction _while searching for a duplicate I know must exist_. Then I'll vote to close. But as @animuson mentioned, partial answers in comments materialize while drawing out all the needed details by probing the OP for more specifics.  "_Are you looking for <some possible outcome>? If so, <some simple solution> is all you need..._"

Comment: ^^ Note it isn't lost on me that I just did the same thing to you. But because I don't know and can't verify that there is really any such trend (it's always been common as I recall) I can't justify this as a real answer.

Comment: Indeed nowadays, almost all my answers come about this way when after several questions in the comment thread, the OP _asks_ me to summarize the comment thread into a proper answer.

Comment: I am not questioning comments where you ask more information to the OP. That is fine, and is what comments are for. I am talking about people posting (even lengthy) comments that actually answer the question.

Comment: On the tag I frequent the most (regex), the question there are mostly crap that a visit to the documentation would solve the problem. That's where I just post my answer in comment.

Comment: Or http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments

Comment: Like @animuson says, it often happens that I spot some problem in lengthy code that will an issue, but probably will not fix the problem that initiated the post by the OP. Since I've spotted it anyway, why not highlight it in a comment?  It's not an answer, but it's useful to the OP anyway and might prevent another SO posting later.

Comment: If my comment turns out to fix the problem, most OP's will comment with something like 'Fixed! Thanks Martin'.  I then copy/paste to an actual answer, and get accepted.

Comment: Some people here point our that sometimes the questions are not too clear. But also many comments do post precise answers to absolutely clear questions. For some reason, the commentor just did not feel like putting it in the answers field.

Answer (score 18):

I have no evidence that providing answers in comments is trending per se, and it is a behavior I observed since my earliest days on the site. In fact, I recall being quite annoyed by it when I was a new user trying to gain reputation and privileges.

One circumstance where answers in comments has always seemed common is to quickly address questions that are highly likely to be downvoted, closed, and deleted with a working solution for the OP. In particular, that applies to questions seeking debugging help, syntax errors, or just common issues that come up every day or dozens of times a day ([search for "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql_fetch_array%28%29+expects+parameter+1+to+be+resource%2C+boolean+given) for an example of what I mean.)

In questions like these, it is likely they have already received at least one downvote, and it is likely they will be closed either as a duplicate or other reason.  Once closed, having no upvoted answers, they can be [more easily deleted automatically by the system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256019/what-if-anything-happens-to-questions-with-a-negative-score/256021#256021), resulting in less site clutter in the long run.

Finally, as I commented above, partial (or even complete) answers materialize in comments while trying to draw out enough details from the OP. In addition to asking the OP for more details, if the answer can be anticipated along with those questions, it may show up in the comment as well. Several times daily, I find myself leaving comments to the effect of:

> "Are you looking for [some possible outcome]? If so, [some simple solution] is all you need to do..."

Sometimes it ends here. Occasionally, the OP may ask for it to be posted as a proper answer and I'll oblige. Often, someone else will just come along and post my comment as an answer, which is fine with me.