# trivial answer : shoud I use comment or answer?

Tags: discussion

relating to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519913/bat-script-to-send-email-if-ping-fails) .
How would you reply in that case : would you write an answer ? a comment ? or a comment then requesting the question to be close as it will likely not help others?

Comment: The odds that this question is going to be helpful to anybody else are negligible.  There's a close reason for typos.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you...  so add a comment and choose close is the right options in those cases

Comment: ^ Ironic answer as comment

Comment: I would comment and vote to close (already closed). http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272642/why-answering-in-comments-is-trending/272644#272644  That question will get deleted, and the non-presence of upvoted answers makes that easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will that question be helpful to other people. Obviously not! This is because that is a minor mistake on the OP's part and the probability of other people getting the same problem is very very low(Almost 0).

So just comment out the mistake(just as [you did](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/27519913/bat-script-to-send-email-if-ping-fails#comment43469688_27519913)) so that the OP will get to know his mistake and then flag it as off-topic with this flag:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.