# Why was my question deleted by "Community"?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

About a month ago I asked this question: [Does Aptana support ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901152/does-aptana-support-es6)

I now see that is has been deleted by the "Community" user.

Prior to its deletion, I saw it receive one "close" vote on the basis on being "too broad", but the voter didn't give any explanation. As I've stated in a comment (prior to the deletion), the question seems quite specific to me.

Could someone help me understand what, if anything, was wrong with the question, and why it was deleted by the "Community" user? Thanks!

Comment: It got autodeleted because of the score, age and lack of answers. See  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256021/168175

Comment: The question wasn't suitable for SO in the first place. It's about configuring a piece of software, not about a programming problem.

Comment: @Cerbrus but Aptana is a tool used by developrers ... and is very much programming related....

Comment: But changing settings in that tool isn't a programming problem.

Comment: Wow, you follow a very strict definition ;)

Comment: Maybe I am, but that's how I see it... If I'm proven wrong by popular opinion / moderators, I'll gladly accept that.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation on [What is on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) of

> software tools commonly used by programmers;

means that questions about an Eclipse based IDE could be on-topic. Based on the comments I understand that changing settings or configuring your toolstack as a developer is not programming related. If that is true you might try to reword the question so it doesn't look like a tool configuration question but its answers will tell you how to configure your tool...

> In Aptana Studio I have the following, I assumed valid, EcmaScript 6 code:
>
> ```
> function* () {
>     yield;
> }
> ```
>
> Strangely enough the IDE reports syntax errors for uses of function* and yield in JavaScript code.
>
> What do I need to do so my code doesn't give syntax errors? I already tried to .... (something you tried)

I still think your initial revision was terse but I wouldn't have closed voted it and if I did my bad...

I voted to undelete your question.

Comment: I think you are right on this. There was just a single down-vote and that made it read-to-be-deleted. I don't see a close vote in the log, so I guess it is all auto-deletion.